Please I'm making a RC plane but my servo motors keeps shaking anytime i connect my transmitter to the receiver pls I'm confused can someone help me
When I first bought it it doesn't behave like that but later anytime I connect my micro zone transmitter to the receiver the servo motors start shaking like it was catching a cold but if I disconnect the transmitter from the receiver it will stop shaking please what is the problem is it really bad

Ok I will remove it I'm sorry

Sorry I'm new here I've not gotten used to it yet can you ask me any question about It I will answer

this site is not a forum... it is your job to describe what you have, how you connected it, what you expected to happen, what actually happened,  and add a question about the problem .... all of that goes into the question, not in comments ... and stop asking for help ... this is a Q&A site, ask a question that helps you when it is answered

Welcome to Robotics, Dave's Wrld. In order to help, we need more information. What troubleshooting steps have you done so far? What happened between the last time it worked correctly and when it started having this problem (in storage for along time, crash, etc.) My guess would be that the batteries are just dead - have you recharged them? Have you taken the steps to synchronize your transmitter and receiver? Is there a section of your manual that provides troubleshooting steps (and what does that say about potential causes and solutions?)
